# How do I fix an "ignoring return value" error?

Tags: c, linux

I don't know why I get this error with `chdir`. I tried to use `if(chdir(C->args[1])==1); else` but it does not work:

```
if(C->arg_count > 1)
{
    chdir(C->args[1]);
}
else
{
    chdir(getenv("HOME"));
}
```

This is the error:

```
error: ignoring return value of ‘chdir’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Werror=unused-result]
    chdir(C->args[1]);
    ^~~~~
```

Comment: You're not looking at the return value of `chdir()`, which lets you know if it's successful or not. Does your application care if it *actually* changes the directory?

Comment: Because your compilation options specified that you should get an error if you don’t test the result from `chdur()`.

Comment: If you write it like this, you have two distinct calls to chdir that need to be checked.  DRY. Create a `const char *` variable and assign it.  Don't forget to check the value returned by `getenv`.  Call `chdir` only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory. You need to check the return value:

```
if(chdir("...") == -1)
{
    perror("chdir");
    /* return error of some sort, don't continue */
}
```

Make sure to replace the comment above with an actual error like `return -1;` (in a function) or `return EXIT_FAILURE;` (in `main`).

Also, `1` is implicitly converted into an `unsigned char`. You don't need the cast.

Answer (score 1):

The function is declared with a special attribute that triggers a warning if you don't check the return value.

If you're *really* not interested whether or not the function is successful, you can cast the return value to `void` to indicate that it isn't being used.

```
(void)chdir(getenv("HOME"));
```

Comment: Nope, `-Werror=unused-result` still complains when the return value is cast to `void`. I'm fraid that's not a viable fix, at least not in CentOS 7 with stock gcc-4.8.5-44.el7